# Vertically centered fluid layout with floats but can't add visible margins

Tags: jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I've been battling with this for a while now, always seeming to get somewhere with one approach, only to then find a problem lurking when I think I'm almost done.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to vertically center content in a div that has a height equal to a percentage of the window height. If the content is taller than that of the containing div, then only some portions of the content should scroll.

Please see [this fiddle result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/verism/G74F9/show/) to get an idea of what I'm trying to do; (actual fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/G74F9/)).

The final (I hope) hurdle is to somehow add a small, fixed amount of space (say, 30px) between the main text and the red "button", when there is enough content to force scrolling. However, everything I've tried - i.e. various combinations of margins and/or padding - just doesn't work. Can somebody please help?

---

**Mandatory Code**

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="heading">HEADING</h1>

            <div id="left">
                <div id="leftContents">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget diam in mi facilisis condimentum. Nullam at arcu erat. Nullam elit libero, sodales sit amet pellentesque et.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#main {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
}
#box{
    position:absolute;
    top:15%; bottom:15%;
    background:white;
    left:50%;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    background:lightgrey;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:lightyellow;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#leftContents{
    /*clear:left;*/
}
#button{
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:25%; right:25%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function alignContent() {
    // Position containing box
    $box = $('#box');
    $box.css({
        'width': $box.height() + 'px',
            'margin-left': '-' + $box.height() / 2 + 'px'
    });
    // Size & position content area
    $content = $('#content');
    $content.css({
        'max-height': $box.height() - 72 + 'px',
            'margin-top': '-' + ($content.outerHeight() / 2) + 'px'
    });
    // Left panel sizing
    $left = $('#left');
    $max = ($box.height() - 72 - 30 - $('#heading').outerHeight());
    $left.css({
        'max-height': $max
    });
}
alignContent();

// Update when resized
$(window).resize(function () {
    alignContent();
});

$(window).load(function () {
    alignContent();
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swap your position absolute for a clear:both?

Like this:

```
#button{
  height:30px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
  left:25%; right:25%;
}
```

If you need the button at the bottom even with little content, use a min-height on the floating divs.

Comment: This breaks the presentation of the "button" - although, the clear property is an understandable suggestion.

Comment: display: inline-block or setting a width for the button should solve the presentation of your button. At least the positioning issue is fixed that way. Using an actual button or input field wouldnt give a full-width button either by the way. You really shouldn't need to use javascript for that positioning. CSS can do it all :)

Comment: In my actual code, it is a `<button>` tag (which, incidentally, you _could_ set as full width if required - although mine is always 50%, hence the absolute positioning), I used divs for ease of typing and presentation. You're right, though, in that everything other than the centring and max-height allocation can be done via CSS.

Comment: actually all can be done with css... using margin 0 auto for horizontal centering, and a negative top margin for vertical centering. You'd just need to have a fixed width/height then, or a fixed border size, or a width/height in percentages. I try at least to give a proper fallback to non-javascript to have my content visible.

Comment: If the content were static, then sure - a constant (CSS) negative top-margin would suffice - but as this is a fluid layout, with content of any size and a container that responds to the window size... sadly, it has to be calculated on the fly. The site is also (and I didn't mention this already) very JS-heavy, so I'm really not concerned about using it as a viable solution - in this case at least.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try adding:

```
    $('#button').css('top', parseInt($content.css('max-height')) - ($('#button').height()) + 'px');
```

To the bottom of your alignContent function.

Comment: All this seems to do is push the button down unnecessarily when content is not scrolling - what is it intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

It took a walk to the shop and back to gain some perspective... then I changed the following lines:

```
#left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:lightyellow;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

became

```
#left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:lightyellow;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}
```

and

```
$max = ($box.height() - 72 - 30 - $('#heading').outerHeight());
```

became

```
$max = ($box.height() - 72 - 60 - $('#heading').outerHeight());
```

Hopefully this will teach me to comment code a little more verbosely if I have to leave it for a couple of days.